# How can i calculate line number relative to cursor postion in TextArea with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

HI Everyone,
 How can i find line number in events like mouse clicked, key down and key up.
 And also highlight that line with color. 
 I used TextArea.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
shivang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you need is contained in `TextField` class. You should use `getLineIndexAtPoint` method of `TextField` to get the line under certain position.

But TextArea hides inner `TextField` class from user.

So, option one is to use `UITextField`.
Option two is extending `TextArea` and implementing required functionality there.

Here is a quick prototype that should help you get started:

```
package test
{
import mx.controls.TextArea;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class HighlightTextArea extends TextArea
{
    public function HighlightTextArea()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function createChildren ():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        textField.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, textField_clickHandler);
    }

    private function textField_clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var lineIndex:int = textField.getLineIndexAtPoint(event.localX, event.localY);
        if (lineIndex == -1)
            return;
        var lineOffset:int = textField.getLineOffset(lineIndex);
        var lineLength:int = textField.getLineLength(lineIndex);
        if (lineLength > 0)
            textField.setTextFormat(new TextFormat(null, null, 0xFF0000), lineOffset, lineOffset+lineLength);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Hrundik. It works.....
But how can i highlight background of particular line?
Thanks again.

Comment: Very useful tip, I didn't know about TextField.getLineIndexAtPoint(). Note that mx.controls.TextArea hides the textField, but fl.controls.TextArea has a public property 'textField'